# Iterate over row from Excel and slice them to store as list in python

Tags: python, list, file-handling

I am using python 3 version and working with excel sheets using xlrd package
currently excel sheet is stored with price numbers in single row as below

```
price
10
22
34
45
```

This numbers will be auto generated in server and row values needed to take out and store in different lists(size of one list is max 10), something like

```
price_list_1 = price.row_values(10)
price_list_2 = price.row_values(11,20)
...
...
```

so that first 10 values could be stored and increment store another 10 values to price_list_2 and so on.
currently for opening and reading I am doing as below.

```
Price_LIST = 'Daily_price_list/' + 'Price_List_2020.xlsx'
PriceList = xlrd.open_workbook(Price_LIST)
List = PriceList.sheet_by_index(0)
```

I have gone through some answers over here and tried but didn't worked out.
need help here.

**EDIT**

I am able to do this via below code.

```
count = 0
for count in range(2, List.nrows):
    if count < 11:
        price_list_1 = List.row_values(count)
        print('\n Printing price_list_1\n',price_list_1)
    elif 10 < count < 21:
        price_list_2 = List.row_values(count)
        print('\n Printing price_list_2\n',price_list_2)
    elif 20 < count < 31:
        price_list_3 = List.row_values(count)
        print('\n Printing price_list_3\n',price_list_3)
    elif 30 < count < 41:
        price_list_4 = List.row_values(count)
        print('\n Printing price_list_4\n',price_list_4)
    elif 40 < count < 51:
        price_list_5 = List.row_values(count)
        print('\n Printing price_list_5\n',price_list_5)
        count + 1
```

with this I am able to split row with 10 values in each list.
Is there any way I can optimize this loop?
**EDIT -2**
While running above code I ran to another problem
when I read values from row's I am getting as below values.

```
['10', '', '', '']
```

The clarification and pointers provided by @Grismar Helped.
To Add, I have different threads( 5 to be precise) running with each price starting from row one till it hits NULL. And each thread will be continuing price one by one till end.

Comment: Am I correct in assuming what you want is to: read a single columns of data from an Excel sheet (skipping the header); then split the data into batches of max 10 items? Your solution seems overly complicated to achieve that, so what else are you trying to do here? What statement resulted in the list `['10', '', '', '']` and what did you expect it to be?

Comment: @Grismar:- Thank you for response, yes your assumption is correct. 
And using xlrd I am reading excel but in the result I am getting output as ```['10', '', '', '']``` Which is string and I am not able to use it.
So, Kindly suggest better way.

Comment: Please don't update a question with more questions that are really about a different problem (or arguably, your initial question wasn't about the problem you had in the first place) - instead work with what you've learnt from the answer and if you run into further problems, or need help with your solution, post a new question about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, you read the entire workbook (in .xlsx format) using `xlrd.open_workbook(Price_LIST)`, select the first sheet using `sheet_by_index(0)` and then proceed to loop over the rows of that sheet by row number (skipping the header), assigning the values of a row to a variable based on the value of the loop parameter.

This results in `price_list_1` having the value of whatever is on row 10, `price_list_2` having the value of whatever is on row 20, etc.

This is not what you're intending, since you appear to want to read all the values, skipping the header and dividing the list into sub-lists of no more than 10 elements each (although it's unclear why you need this). It also doesn't scale, since you would run into issues if the sheet had more than 50 values.

The desired result can be achieved with only a few lines of code:

```
import xlrd

# get the first sheet from the workbook
price_sheet = xlrd.open_workbook('price.xlsx').sheet_by_index(0)

# get all the values from the first column, skipping the first line
values = price_sheet.col_values(0, 1)
# get values in groups of 10
groups_of_ten = [values[i:i+10] for i in range(0, len(values), 10)]

print(groups_of_ten)
```

Comment: So basically to elaborate, I have multi threads( 5 max) running same process but with different price_list. Ex. I have different price in bunch of 10's in list. With those lists I will be running different thread for each and every price to check online and compare. ones the thread finishes it's own list, then it can update from main or as you suggested, one list can be updated from which each thread process, but it will be difficult when one price is not available and first thread need to check price for next.

Comment: If your aim is to provide data to be processed on multiple threads, you would do well to look into the Queue class https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html, which would allow you to read prices from the queue whenever a thread is done, instead of synchronising on batches of prices.

Comment: I think that's both too long and too complicated a conversation to be having in a comment thread - also well beyond the scope of the question.

Comment: Thank you for queue class pointer, it would be helpful if you can point me to some implementation examples So that I can understand and implement

Comment: I think there's excellent examples in the documentation here? https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html under "Queue objects" - you should probably take some of the examples there, try to solve your problem with it and if you run into issues, post a new question with specific issues.